# JMS message sent with JMSXGroupId to ActiveMQ Artemis queue on one server in a cluster does not get delivered to consumer connected to another server

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

A JMS message with JMSXGroupId sent to a dynamic queue on ActiveMQ Artemis server from Java code (JDK 11) does not get delivered to consumer connected to another server. Is this normal behavior? Is there a way to allow distribution of messages with GroupId to remote servers/listeners? I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.29.0.

Comment: Clustered message grouping relies on a properly functioning cluster as well as a properly configured `grouping-handler` on each node. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-grouping.html#clustered-grouping) for more details on that. Have you configured all this properly?

Comment: Any feedback here?

Comment: After carefully reading the documentation, it seems the better approach is to avoid message grouping unless absolutely required, so currently working on removing all unnecessary message grouping, which did not cause issues, when ActiveMQ servers were utilized. Thanks for the advice. I will add comment(s), if and when message grouping is used with the current ActiveMQ Artemis servers